# How to make inner html elements drag along with parent element in d3 js

Tags: d3.js

Below is generated html:

```
<g title="some" cx="308" cy="98">
   <circle class="node" cx="308" cy="98" r="20" style="stroke: gray; fill: white;">
   <text dx="298" dy="103">some</text>
</g>
```

When I drag this element, cx and cy of only outer g element changes. And circle and text remains at the same position.

I want circle and text to be dragged along with g element when I drag it.

Here is my code of generating node:

```
node = container.append("g").selectAll("svg.node")
                .data(json.nodes)
                .enter().append("g").call(drag);
            node.append("svg:circle")
                .attr("cx",function(nodeObj) { return (nodeObj.x);})
                .attr("cy",function(nodeObj) { return (nodeObj.y);})
                .attr("r", 20)
                .style("stroke", "gray")
                .style("fill", "white");
            node.append("text")
                .attr("dx",function(nodeObj) { return (nodeObj.x - 10);})
                .attr("dy",function(nodeObj) { return (nodeObj.y + 5);})
                .text(function(nodeObj) {return nodeObj.name;});
            node.attr("title",function(nodeObj) {return nodeObj.name;});
```

Drag behavior:

```
        drag = d3.behavior.drag()
                .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragmove)
                .on("dragend", dragended);

        dragmove = function (nodeObj) {
            nodeObj.x += d3.event.dx;
            nodeObj.y += d3.event.dy; 
            tick(); // this is the key to make it work together with updating both px,py,x,y on d !
        };

        dragstarted = function () {
           d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
           d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
        };

        dragended = function (nodeObj) {
            if (d3.event.sourceEvent.which == 1){   
                  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
                  tick();
            }
        };

        tick = function () {
            link.attr("x1", function(nodeObj) { return nodeObj.source.x; })
               .attr("y1", function(nodeObj) { return nodeObj.source.y; })
               .attr("x2", function(nodeObj) { return nodeObj.target.x; })
               .attr("y2", function(nodeObj) { return nodeObj.target.y; });

            node.attr("cx",function(nodeObj) { return (nodeObj.x);})
            node.attr("cy",function(nodeObj) { return (nodeObj.y);})

            force.stop();
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

In SVG, `g` elements don't have `cx` and `cy` attributes -- setting them won't have any effect. What you need to set is the `transform` attribute, e.g. to `translate(<x>,<y>)`. So the code to update the node positions would be

```
node.attr("transform", function(nodeObj) {
  return "translate(" + nodeObj.x + "," + nodeObj.y + ")";
});
```

Also note that the force layout already provides a facility for dragging the nodes, there's no need to use the drag behaviour in addition:

```
container.call(force.drag);
```

See e.g. [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045).

Comment: Not working..This causes all elements on layout render..@Lars Kotthoff

Comment: Could you provide a complete example please?

Comment: Ok, you were setting the coordinates on the circles and text elements again, which you don't need to do in this case. The zoom and drag behaviours you've added were interfering with the node drag. I've removed those and made the changes I've suggested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DYa2N/1/).

Comment: Yea circle and text are moving with outer 'g' element but initially I want nodes at positions as specified in nodes' array with x and y..which I'm not getting with your solution...@Lars Kotthoff

Comment: You are getting that, the positions are just immediately changed by the force layout. You can see that if you stop the layout immediately after starting it and call `tick()` once -- http://jsfiddle.net/DYa2N/2/

Comment: Yea correct...now what if I don't want charge and the position of node to be equal to the position where I drop it after dragging?? And if I drag one node, it should not affect other nodes or their positions...@Lars Kotthoff

Comment: On a side note, if you're not using the force layout to position the nodes, then you could get rid of it.

Comment: what is its alternative? @Lars Kotthoff

Comment: You have node positions in your JSON already -- you don't need anything to compute them if you want the nodes to stay there.

Comment: Calculation is included to get node positions after dragging..Is there any better solution to do the same thing in another way? @Lars Kotthoff

Comment: As I've said, you wouldn't need the force layout for that -- but it's certainly easiest to stick with what you have if that works for you.